# How to test load a web application?

Tags: jsf, web-applications, load-testing

I am working on a web app which uses JSF. I would like to know that What are best practices and available tools for performing a load test on it.

Application is hosted on glassfish server 3.1.2.2

Comment: Try webdriver using grid configuration.

Comment: How do i test if my application has its own authentication mechanism.

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: I am using an third party api...and my application is just chanellizig things between user and th api. So the users are directly users of the api. Api has its own authentication, without authentication nothing is accesdible..

Comment: So then simply integrate webdriver API in there too.

Answer (score 1):

Depends somewhat on the site you want to test. At work we have a complex RIA, and to test it we have to reproduce user interaction. We use [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for this.

It's kind of messy to set up (look at the guides they have) but once this is done it's very flexible and allows you to configure and tweak many things. I particularly like its "proxy" feature where you can proxy your app through jMeter and it records everything so you can play it back later on. Note that for JSF you have to do some tricks with the ViewStateId, so google a "jmeter JSF" guide for how to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

In a previous project I have used [RadView WebLOAD](http://radview.com/) to test a JSF site, it enable recording the user scenario and handles correlating the dynamic values.